# How to find CSS applied rules of HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to find, say, all the elements on a page that have `margin-left` with JavaScript?

Comment: technically everything has a margin-left... I am assuming that has a value set? inline? CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your question is a bit broad, but I am going to say you want all elements where the margin-left is set to a number not equal to zero.

So you can select all the elements, loop over the list, checking each ones margin, and filtering them out.

With ES6:

```
const elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*')).filter(e => parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(e).getPropertyValue('margin-left'))!=0)
```

Comment: ah, was supposed to be not equal, getting late :) (I said not equal in my description and code it with a > lol....)